# rubymine custom tab character style?

Tags: tabs, character, rubymine

I  checked `"use tab character"` and `"show whitespaces"`,  At this time my ruby page look like this  http://d.pr/i/aHSv. how i convert tab character style like my vim style  like this http://d.pr/i/tpGp

rubymine to support custom tab character style? how i setting it?

macox rubymine 4.5.2 build #RM-119.46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyMine has no setting to customize the tab symbol appearance in the editor.